# Need to create WS Infura connection with JWT

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, infura

Im developing a web app in which I connect the client with infura using ws and the project id, but I also need to use JWT in order to add an extra layer of security. There are explanations in infura documentation about how to include JWT when making https calls, but none when using ws. Which is the proper way to secure using a jwt?